# Different txManager with same DAO, want inject Connection of ConnectionHolder into persistence

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have an application that copy data from one DB to an other DB. On both DB's the same DB schema is installed. When we copy data a lot of business logic is needed.
We have a typical, traditional implementation with a service, dao and a custom persistence layer (no entity manager).

First I start to define two datasources used by two different transaction managers.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class TestEnvironment {


    /**
     * Configuration for the database datasource 1
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Bean(name = { "DataSource1"})
    public DataSource basicDatasource1() {
            ...
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager txManagerDB1() {
        DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        dataSourceTransactionManager.setDataSource(basicDatasource1());

        return dataSourceTransactionManager;
    }

    /**
     * Configuration for the database datasource 2
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Bean(name = { "DataSource2"})
    public DataSource basicDatasource2() {
            ...
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager txManagerDB2() {
        DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        dataSourceTransactionManager.setDataSource(basicDatasource2());

        return dataSourceTransactionManager;
    }

}
```

Then I implement my Service and inject via @Autowired my test DAO.
I implement two methods using the same DAO (reentrant). This two methods in my Service I annotate with @Transactional and set respectively the txManager I want to use.

```
@Service
@Primary
public class MyTestServiceImpl extends AbstractHandler implements MyTestService {

    @Autowired
    private TxManagerTestDao txManagerTestDao;

    @Transactional("txManagerDB1")
    public String callToDB1() {
        txManagerTestDao.setTransactionName("txManagerDB1");
        return txManagerTestDao.loadTestBean().getTestString();
    }

    /*
     * Return DB Connection Type
     */
    @Transactional("txManagerDB2")
    public String callToDB2() {
        txManagerTestDao.setTransactionName("txManagerDB2");
        return txManagerTestDao.loadTestBean().getTestString();
    }

}
```

The line txManagerTestDao.setTransactionName("txManagerDB1") or txManagerTestDao.setTransactionName("txManagerDB2") is bad design I want to remove. Because, I need that only to know in the DAO layer what transaction manager I want to use to set the active connection to my persistence layer.

My DAO looks like the following:

```
@Repository
public class TxManagerTestDaoImpl implements TxManagerTestDao {

    private String transactionName;

    @Autowired
    private AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireBeanFactory;

    public TestBean loadTestBean() {

        DataSourceTransactionManager myTransaction = (DataSourceTransactionManager) autowireBeanFactory.getBean(transactionName);
        ConnectionHolder conHolder = (ConnectionHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(myTransaction.getDataSource());

        //conHolder.getConnection() is know the correct connection I have to use due to the @Transactional in my servide layer.
        //HOW CAN I GET WITH A GENERIC WAY THE ACTIVE TRANSACTION MANAGER?

        TestBean testBean = new TestBean();
        testBean.setTestString("myTransaction: '" + myTransaction + "' Connection: '" + conHolder.getConnection() + "'");

        return testBean;
    }

    @Override
    public void setTransactionName(String transactionName) {
        this.transactionName = transactionName;
    }
}
```

I want to set the active txManager via @Transactional("...") as I did it in my service layer. I will not use in the future txManagerTestDao.setTransactionName("txManagerDB2") in an redundant way.
The solution works perfect, but is not perfect to implement for our special use case.

Is there a generic way to found out in the method TxManagerTestDaoImpl.loadTestBean() if txManagerDB1 or txManagerDB2 is active?
As a result I need the active ConnectionHolder Object of my active Transaction.
The I inject that Connection into my Persistence, then all classes runs in the same Transaction.
The DAO and the persistence Layer should be neutral. Our persistence is only a DataMapper from/to SQL. I want/can not use JPA or a similar framework.

Thanks

Comment: I don't quite sure what you trying to achieve, but i recommend you to read this article: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html

Comment: Thanks.
No, I know this topic. My problem is not that I want to use XA Transactions. I want to detect the current, active DataSourceTransactionManager as I showed by using a generic way.